# Attaching a file from FTP to PHPMailer class

Tags: php, ftp, phpmailer

Hey guys i am trying to automate my system at work for sending artwork to clients, i am trying to make it so i can upload my final artwork pdf files (which i done) then later on when i select to send them an email it will attach it and send it off.
I have tried doing it this way

$mail->AddAttachment('http://#######.com.au/artwork/14653/16296/Final/Final.pdf');

Now i didn't have much hope for this working but i thought i would give it a try,
does anyone know how to take a file directly fro, the ftp and attach it, or at least save the trouble of downloading it then browsing for it and attaching.

Thanks in advance SOF guys.

Comment: also just giving them a hyperlink to the file is not an option i would like to visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://www.phpguru.org/static/mime.mail.html